# How to checkout tagged AOSP?

Tags: git, android-source, repo

I figured out creating a release tag for an AOSP tree

```
repo forall -c 'git tag release-v2'

repo forall -c 'git push aosp release-v2'
```

but what would be the repo/git workflow to freshly checkout this tagged release?

Answer (score 0):

Use `repo manifest -r -o foo.xml` to save the manifest as `foo.xml`. Add and commit `foo.xml` to a branch of your manifest repository.

In future, you or others can use `repo init -u <url_to_manifest_repository> -b <branch> -m foo.xml && repo sync -c -d` to checkout this tagged release.